# React renders based on state change but not on prop change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fibers

The reason I'm having this question is that I do not see how React renders based on prop changes.

On each fiber, `beginWork` renders the fiber, and if there's any state change, it'll mark the change. And if there isn't, it could `bailoutOnAlreadyFinishedWork` so  to clone the fiber. While doing it, it `reconcileChildren` so that we know what's the next work unit. During the `reconcileChildren`, seems to me the the `pendingProps` for each element is used directly.

The question is that I do not see when the props are shallow compared. I only see the code that I expected in `React.memo` with `shallowEqual` and then confirmed with the doc, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo.

So where the props are not checked shallowly by default? Does that mean as long as there's a render, it'll carry the props as a new version?

Thanks if someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer in this article, https://medium.com/takeaway-tech/a-deep-dive-into-pure-component-and-react-memo-and-why-do-we-need-them-ae99dce6a33c .

It firmly says

> Remember: in React, props is immutable object.

And unless `React.memo` is used, props are rendered all the time!!!

Under the `beginWork`, React does compare the props before it goes into a new render. Here's the source code

```
function beginWork(current, workInProgress, renderLanes) {
  ...
  if (current !== null) {
    var oldProps = current.memoizedProps;
    var newProps = workInProgress.pendingProps;

    if (oldProps !== newProps || hasContextChanged() || ( // Force a re-render if the implementation changed due to hot reload:
     workInProgress.type !== current.type )) {
      // If props or context changed, mark the fiber as having performed work.
      // This may be unset if the props are determined to be equal later (memo).
      didReceiveUpdate = true;
```

However `oldProps !== newProps` is not doing a shallow check, instead it's similar to `object.is`. And for props, `{} !== {}` unless it's a cloned copy. Therefore seems to me, props isn't implemented as *React* advertised it :)

Of course, if there's no state change ,it wouldn't even get into a prop change. So maybe as long as we make sure state is compared correctly, it'll translate into correct rendering? I don't know if this is the correct rational here.

Comment: I said exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. If the parent state is updated whether it is a redux state or hook it will re render it's all components. But there is a case. Suppose you implemented your child in a way that it will only re render if the props are changed. Then even if the parent re render all it's child the child will not re render itself. This process in react is called **memoization**. But yes if parent state it updated it will re render all it's child

Reference - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo